# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript

Eu não consigo compreender por que está acontecendo este erro. Teoricamente o erro se deve a não ter este ID no html, mas ele existe... até troquei o nome verificar se algo estava escrito errado...

```
<tr class="paciente">
                    <td class="info-nome">Paulo</td>
                    <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
                    <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
                    <
```

Veja o Js...

```
    var tdpeso = document.getElementById("peso-2");
var tdaltura = document.getElementById("altura-2");

var peso = tdpeso.textContent;
var altura = tdaltura.textContent;


if (altura != 0) {
 var imc = peso / (altura * altura);

 console.log(imc);
 }else{
    console.log("Impossível executar pois altura é igual a zero");
 }
```

Comment: No teu HTML tens `<` no final, podes corrigir? talvez seja `</tr>`? Pergunta: onde está o JavaScript na página?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, esse problema ocorre devido a importação do javascript está acontecendo antes do objeto ser criado, se você colocar a importação do script uma linha antes do "" vai poder manipular todos os objetos da página tranquilamente.